# Connecting slots and signals in PyQt4 in a loop

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots

Im trying to build a calculator with PyQt4 and connecting the 'clicked()' signals from the buttons doesn't work as expected.
Im creating my buttons for the numbers inside a for loop where i try to connect them afterwards.

```
def __init__(self):
    for i in range(0,10):
        self._numberButtons += [QPushButton(str(i), self)]
        self.connect(self._numberButtons[i], SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda : self._number(i))

def _number(self, x):
    print(x)
```

When I click on the buttons all of them print out '9'.
Why is that so and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is just, how scoping, name lookup and closures are defined in Python.

Python only introduces new bindings in namespace through assignment and through parameter lists of functions.  `i` is therefore not actually defined in the namespace of the `lambda`, but in the namespace of `__init__()`.  The name lookup for `i` in the lambda consequently ends up in the namespace of `__init__()`, where `i` is eventually bound to `9`.  This is called "closure".

You can work around these admittedly not really intuitive (but well-defined) semantics by passing `i` as a keyword argument with default value.  As said, names in parameter lists introduce new bindings in the local namespace, so `i` inside the `lambda` then becomes independent from `i` in `.__init__()`:

```
self._numberButtons[i].clicked.connect(lambda checked, i=i: self._number(i))
```

<sup>UPDATE: `clicked` has a default `checked` argument that would override the value of `i`, so it *must* be added to the argument list before the keyword value.</sup>

A more readable, less magic alternative is `functools.partial`:

```
self._numberButtons[i].clicked.connect(partial(self._number, i))
```

I'm using new-style signal and slot syntax here simply for convenience, old style syntax works just the same.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with the functools.partial solution.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating closures. Closures really capture a variable, not the value of a variable. At the end of `__init__`, `i` is the last element of `range(0, 10)`, i.e. `9`. All the lambdas you created in this scope refer to this `i` and only when they are invoked, they get the value of `i` at the time they are at invoked (however, seperate invocations of `__init__` create lambdas referring to seperate variables!).

There are two popular ways to avoid this:

1. Using a default parameter: `lambda i=i: self._number(i)`. This work because default parameters bind a value at function definition time.
2. Defining a helper function `helper = lambda i: (lambda: self._number(i))` and use `helper(i)` in the loop. This works because the "outer" `i` is evaluated at the time `i` is bound, and - as mentioned before - the next closure created in the next invokation of `helper` will refer to a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Qt` way, use [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsignalmapper.html) instead.

Comment: Please don't.  `QSignalMapper` is a remnant of C++ 98, which does not have lambdas or partial functions and where such workaround are a necessary evil.  In Python however `QSignalMapper` is simply superfluous and really bloated compared to `functools.partial()` or lambda.  Solutions with `partial()` or `lambda` are shorter and more elegant than `QSignalMapper`.

Comment: Oh well its about the choice, I would choose `QSignalMapper` for Qt/C++ compatibility.

Comment: Of course it's about the choice, but I simply don't understand your choice and I can't follow it.  I'm using Python for Qt applications exactly because it is *not* C++, and if I'd abandon all of Python's special features to maintain or to reach C++ compatibility, I could just as well use C++ ;)