# Connecting multiples signal/slot in a for loop in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

I'm connecting multiple signal/slots using a `for loop` in PyQt. The code is bellow:

```
# Connect Scan Callbacks
for button in ['phase', 'etalon', 'mirror', 'gain']:
    getattr(self.ui, '{}_scan_button' .format(button)).clicked.connect(
        lambda: self.scan_callback(button))
```

What I expect:

- Connect button `phase_scan_button` clicked `signal` to the `scan_callback` `slot` and send the string `phase` as a parameter to the `slot`. The same for `etalon`, `mirror` and `gain`.

What I'm getting:

- For some reason my functions is always passing the string `gain` as parameter for all the buttons. Not sure if I'm being stupid (likely) or it is a bug.

For reference, the `slot` method:

```
def scan_callback(self, scan):
    print(scan) # Here I always get 'gain'
    if self.scanner.isWorking:
        self.scanner.isWorking = False
        self.scan_thread.terminate()
        self.scan_thread.wait()
    else:
        self.scanner.isWorking = True
        self.scan_thread.start()
        getattr(self.ui, '{}_scan_button' .format(
            scan)).setText('Stop Scan')
        getattr(self, '_signal{}Scan' .format(scan)).emit()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My preferred way of iterating over several widgets in pyqt is storing them as objects in lists.

```
myButtons = [self.ui.phase_scan_button, self.ui.etalon_scan_button,
             self.ui.mirror_scan_button, self.ui.gain_scan_button]
for button in myButtons:
    button.clicked.connect(lambda _, b=button: self.scan_callback(scan=b))
```

If you need the strings "phase", "etalon", "mirror" and "gain" separately, you can either store them in another list, or create a dictionary like

```
myButtons_dict = {"phase": self.ui.phase_scan_button,
                 "etalon": self.ui.etalon_scan_button,
                 "mirror": self.ui.mirror_scan_button,
                 "gain": self.ui.gain_scan_button}

for button in myButtons_dict:
    myButtons_dict[button].clicked.connect(lambda: _, b=button self.scan_callback(scan=b))
```

Note, how I use the lambda expression with solid variables that are then passed into the function `self.scan_callback`. This way, the value of `button` is stored for good.

Comment: Please note GPhilo's answer aswell. He points out the problem of your approach, whereas my approach only helps you manage widgets and names!

Comment: I did. Both are great answers, really hard to choose which one to accept

Comment: @offeltoffel I'm curious though... how is this different from the attempt the OP did? You're still defining a lambda that uses the value of `button`, which in theory should be evaluated at runtime. Why is this not the case?

Comment: GPhilo: You are completely right. I just tested it and found the same problem. It works though, if "button" is stored to another variable in the lambda expression (see updated version). Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @offeltoffel Nice trick in your last edit, although I'd have kept simply `self.scan_callback(b)` since specifying `scan=b` is redundant. @Eduardo, if you're wondering why this works with the seemingly minor change, [have a look at this amazing question and its answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: @GPhilo: I think what you call redundancy is more a matter of taste. Of course `self.scan_callback(b)` is the same as `self.scan_callback(scan=b)` but I personally like to keep track of which value is passed to which argument of the function. It get's nasty when there are 3 or more variables to pass.

Answer (score 3):

Your lambdas do **not** store the *value* of `button` when it is defined. The code describing the lambda function is parsed and compiled **but not executed until you actually call the lambda**.
Whenever any of the buttons is clicked, the *current value of variable* `button` is used. At the end of the loop, `button` contains `"gain"` and this causes the behaviour you see.

Try this:

```
funcs = []
for button in ['phase', 'etalon', 'mirror', 'gain']:
    funcs.append( lambda : print(button))

for fn in funcs:
  fn()
```

The output is:

```
gain
gain
gain
gain
```

Extending the example, as a proof that the lambdas don't store the value of `button` note that if `button` stops existing, you'll have an error:

```
del button
for fn in funcs:
  fn()
```

which has output

```
funcs.append( lambda : print(button))
NameError: name 'button' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is very clear to me now. I, however, opted for @offeltoffel's answer because he proposed solutions for the issue. If I could, I would definitively accept both as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted here : [Connecting slots and signals in PyQt4 in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578861/connecting-slots-and-signals-in-pyqt4-in-a-loop)
Using `functools.partial` is a nice workaround for this problem.

Have been struggling with same problem as OP for a day.