# Referencing child widgets (QPushButton) in QScrollArea only refers to the last instance of the button object, regardless of which button is clicked

Tags: python, object, pyqt5

Alright, so I'm pretty deep into an app I'm making using PyQt5 and I have a section (QScrollArea) where I essentially have multiple lines of "accounts" which are QWidgets. The user can add an account and delete an account, but I would like to give them the ability to edit an account.  On the same row as the account is a QPushButton, which is basically the edit button.  If I have 3 accounts, then I can see 3 buttons.  However, when I click the button for any account, all of the buttons refer to the exact same button object.  I am storing the objects in a list and using findChildren() to get the objects.  Both of these will give me three different button objects, but using clicked.connect() with the buttons reference only the latest, or bottom-most, button.

I am calling the clicked.connect() function after the part of my code that adds the account.  I have also tried moving this to right below where I instantiate the button, but it didn't work.

Here is what I have:

```
btns = self.accountsWidget.findChildren(QPushButton)
    for btn in btns:
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.editAccount(btn))
```

The method I call to try to edit the account is here:

```
    def editAccount(self, btn):
        print(btn)
        self.editAccountWindow = EditAccountsWindow()
        self.editAccountWindow.show()
```

The result of what's printed is always the last QPushButton object, and I'm only printing to see if I referenced the button I wanted to. That method just opens up a window, but what's shown on the window depends on calling the correct object.  I want to use the object to reference which account I want to edit.

I have looked on many SO threads and could not find anything similar to this.  I think I'm missing something, so please help a brother out :)

Comment: See [`sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender)

Comment: @alec thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Comment: Have a look at [Connecting multiples signal/slot in a for loop in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300229/connecting-multiples-signal-slot-in-a-for-loop-in-pyqt), and do some research about scope and closure with Python and lambda. Also, consider that a *possible* alternative is to use `functools.partial` instead of lambda.

Comment: @musicamante I ordered a PyQt5 book a couple days ago so I could learn more about topics like that. And lambda functions just came easily to me in that scenario, but I'll look into functoools as well.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Remember that lambas and partials are not "directly related" to PyQt (they're part of Python, PyQt just "obeys" to their behavior), and they are *alternatives*: while partial behavior is *similar* to lambda, they're **not** the same (especially for variable scope/closure), and you have to learn how decide which one use. I usually prefer lambda over partial (lambdas can be too verbose, but I like their "descriptiveness"; nonetheless that choice is also a matter of code style and personal habit/preference). Anyway, you *must* understand their concepts, despite you're dealing with PyQt or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def editAccount(self, objects):
    sender = self.sender()
    index = 0
    for object in objects:
        if sender == object:
            account = account_handler.get_account(index) 
            ...

widgets = self.accountsScrollView.findChildren(QWidget, "accountsWidget")
for widget in widgets:
    editButtons = widget.findChildren(QPushButton, 'editButtonAccounts')
    for e in range(0, len(editButtons)):
        editButtons[e].clicked.connect(lambda: self.editAccount(edit_objects_list))
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but, while *conceptually* your answer *might* be right, it has a lot of issues. First of all, you should always provide an explanation for your answers (code-only answer are not very welcome), and the indentation is wrong; then, `edit_objects_list` is never declared; it's not very performant; using `range()` with 0 as first argument is unnecessary as it's implied; cycling through a list like that is also unnecessary, you can just cycle through objects found with findChildren: `for widget in widget.findChildren(QPushButton, 'editButtonAccounts'): ...`;

Comment: string based search within children should only be done when no other alternative is available: non-unique object names are discouraged, and whether you're using pyuic/uic or coded GUIs, you always have unique names, so, for custom built GUIs there's not much sense with `findChildren` at all; as soon as the object match has been found in the `for` cycle of `editAccount()`, there should be a `break`; there also should be an `index += 1`, or an `enumerate` in the for cycle; finally (sorry again, I'm very strict), on the code styling side of things, you should either use single or double quotes.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry I'm just seeing this now, but thank you for your explanation.  I have revised the code as you suggested and of course it works great.  The reason I use findChildren() is because the number of children constantly changes, and I need to access a certain child at a certain time.

Comment: I can understand it, but remember that SO is not a "personal" Q&A site, as it's intended for long and persisting answers that can help *anybody*. If you want to provide an answer to your own question, that's fine (actually, it's very welcome!), but you should always ensure that that answer **is** helpful to other people too, especially if they don't know the context you're working with. The "power" of SO resides in its *existing* answers (that's why we all use it), so if an answer has enough context, it is helpful for *everybody*, not just you. Please, remember that, as it's really important.