# How to connect multiple PyQt Signals w/ variable arguments to single slot/signal repeater

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-signals

Example:

```
class MyClass(QObject):
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal(str, int)
    signal_2 = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    signal_3 = pyqtSignal(str, int, int)
```

Let's say each of these signals is connected elsewhere to perform various functions, however, there's a specific function I want to be performed as well when *any* of the signals are emitted. What this indiscriminate function does cares only about, say, the last `int` argument emitted with the signal. The slot would ostensibly look like:

```
class OtherClass(QObject):

    ...

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def unifiedResponse(self, index):
        # Here I would do something with that index
```

Is there a way to connect some arbitrary number of signals with arbitrary arguments either directly to a slot or to a repeater signal?

If there is a way to define a slot like so:

```
@pyqtSlot(???)
def unifiedResponse(self, *args):
    important_var = args[-1]
```

Then I could simply capture the last argument as such. However, I have been unsuccessful in determining how to form the slot signature.

**Update:**

I may have answered my own question, using `lambda`s:

```
signal_1.connect(lambda _, source: OtherClass.unifiedResponse(source))
signal_2.connect(lambda _, source: OtherClass.unifiedResponse(source))
signal_3.connect(lambda _, _, source: OtherClass.unifiedResponse(source))
```

The solution from @eyllanesc below however is preferred, as it allows for more flexibility the larger the signal count.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting slots and signals in PyQt4 in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578861/connecting-slots-and-signals-in-pyqt4-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set all the signatures of the signals through several pyqtSlot:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QCoreApplication, QObject, QTimer


class MyClass(QObject):
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal(str, int)
    signal_2 = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    signal_3 = pyqtSignal(str, int, int)


class OtherClass(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(str, int)
    @pyqtSlot(int, int)
    @pyqtSlot(str, int, int)
    def unifiedResponse(self, *args):
        print(args)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    sender = MyClass()
    receiver = OtherClass()

    sender.signal_1.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)
    sender.signal_2.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)
    sender.signal_3.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)

    def on_timeout():
        sender.signal_1.emit("StackOverflow", 1)
        sender.signal_2.emit(1, 2)
        sender.signal_3.emit("StackOverflow", 1, 2)

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, QCoreApplication.quit)

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, on_timeout)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

If in general you want to send several types of data then it is best to use a more generic data type such as a list (or an object):

```
class MyClass(QObject):
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal(list)
    signal_2 = pyqtSignal(list)
    signal_3 = pyqtSignal(list)


class OtherClass(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(list)
    def unifiedResponse(self, args):
        print(args)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    sender = MyClass()
    receiver = OtherClass()

    sender.signal_1.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)
    sender.signal_2.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)
    sender.signal_3.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)

    def on_timeout():
        sender.signal_1.emit(["StackOverflow", 1])
        sender.signal_2.emit([1, 2])
        sender.signal_3.emit(["StackOverflow", 1, 2])

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, QCoreApplication.quit)

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, on_timeout)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

There is no elegant way to access the last element, but the first ones since the slot signature must be a subset of the signal signature, for example the slot with signature "int" can accept signals with a signature that has the first type to "int", the other arguments are discarded:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QCoreApplication, QObject, QTimer


class MyClass(QObject):
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal(int, str)
    signal_2 = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    signal_3 = pyqtSignal(int, str, int)


class OtherClass(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def unifiedResponse(self, index):
        print(index)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    sender = MyClass()
    receiver = OtherClass()

    sender.signal_1.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)
    sender.signal_2.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)
    sender.signal_3.connect(receiver.unifiedResponse)

    def on_timeout():
        sender.signal_1.emit(1, "StackOverflow")
        sender.signal_2.emit(2, 2)
        sender.signal_3.emit(3, "StackOverflow", 1)

        QTimer.singleShot(1000, QCoreApplication.quit)

    QTimer.singleShot(1000, on_timeout)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Oh man that is... not ideal. But if this is the only way then I suppose I should try approaching the problem from a different angle.

Comment: @ConnorSpangler What kind of answers did you expect? Maybe you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't believe so. I have multiple signals which indicate to a paint application when things have updated e.g. pixels or colors etc. When undoing and redoing, I want the app to switch to the appropriate tab in the application, which is identified with a variable that is already passed in these signals. Whenever these signals are emitted, one slot connected to all of them could grab that index and switch to the appropriate tab. I was really hoping there was a way to connect a signal to a slot but only pass some of the signal arguments.

Comment: @ConnorSpangler Why is the index in the last position? If you were in the first one then there is a solution.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, simply a standard that arose naturally. I'm certainly willing and able to change the argument order.

Comment: Ah I have even accidentally stumbled on that behavior before. Didn't consider to use it as a feature! I found something of a solution myself using lambdas, outlined in my update.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having problems to connect multiple PyQt Signals with variable arguments to a single slot.

That was the solution I found for connecting all the widgets from **input_lineEdit_widgets** to **validate_values**

```
class View_Controller():

    def connect_signals(self,ui):

        #This is a list of lineEdit widgets from a QtWidgets.QMainWindow (ui)
        input_lineEdit_widgets = [ui.prim_press_lineEdit, ui.gas_vol_lineEdit, ui.melt_1_temp_lineEdit,
                                 ui.melt_1_time_lineEdit, ui.melt_1_flow_lineEdit, ui.melt_2_temp_lineEdit,
                                 ui.melt_2_time_lineEdit, ui.melt_2_flow_lineEdit]

        for widgets in input_lineEdit_widgets:
            widgets.textChanged.connect(lambda *args, widgets = widgets: self.validate_values(widgets))


    def validate_values(self, widget):
        print(widget.objectName())
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4578943/3335606)